# Auto Load Newest Version of File

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to run a render farm in Blender through a shared folder with the Placeholders option turned on and the Overwrite option turned off. Since I'm using a shared folder, I have to open the .blend file on all of the computers. This means that every time I make a save on one computer, I have to reopen the file on all of the other computers, which is a bit of a hassle, considering that I save quite often. I was wondering if there is a script or a built in Blender function that automatically loads the newest version of a file when a new save occurs. Does anyone know of any option that would do this?